# Return in switch block behaves differently between Core and Classic PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

The following script gives different results when it is run on 5.1 compared to 7.4.0.

```
function foo($x) {
    $val = switch ($x){
        1 { 5 }
        default {
            return 10 
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Val is $val" 
    $val + 1
}

Write-Host "foo 1: $(foo 1)" 
Write-Host "foo 2: $(foo 2)"
```

PS 5.1 output:

```
Val is 5
foo 1: 6
foo 2: 10
```

PS 7.4.0 output:

```
Val is 5
foo 1: 6    
foo 2:
```

Is this a bug in PS Core (it's certainly unexpected to me) or is this a documented change/was always undefined behavior?

Comment: Looks like a bug introduced in `7.4.0`, the expression after the `return` statement is routed to the assignment target (`$local:val`) instead of being output to the caller.

Comment: Just for other readers (Matthias already knows since he also commented on it ;-)), this seems to be a bug introduced in 7.4.0.  I created a bug report [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20739) in the official repo. 
The code works fine in 7.3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in PowerShell 7.4.0 (which will hopefully be fixed in the next release).

See [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20739) bug report.